# how to include C++ input stream delimiters into result tokens

Tags: c++, iostream

C++ standard library supports a few ways to introduce custom delimiters for input streams, as I understand recommended way is a using new locale and ctype objects:

first way (inherited from ctype specialization) :

```
struct csv_whitespace : std::ctype<char>
{
    bool do_is(mask m, char_type c) const
    {
        if ((m & space) && c == ' ') {
            return false; // space will NOT be classified as whitespace
        }
        if ((m & space) && c == ',') {
            return true; // comma will be classified as whitespace
        }
        return ctype::do_is(m, c); // leave the rest to the parent class
    }
};
//  for cin stream :
cin.imbue(std::locale(cin.getloc(), new csv_whitespace));
```

second way (parameterized ctype specialization):

```
//  getting existing table for ctype<char> specialization
const auto temp = std::ctype<char>::classic_table();
//  create a copy of the table in vector container
std::vector<std::ctype<char>::mask> new_table_vector(temp, temp + std::ctype<char>::table_size);

//  add/remove stream separators using bitwise arithmetic.
//  use char-based indices because ascii codes here are equal to indices
new_table_vector[' '] ^= ctype_base::space;
new_table_vector['\t'] &= ~(ctype_base::space | ctype_base::cntrl);
new_table_vector[':'] |= ctype_base::space;
//  A ctype initialized with new_table_vector would delimit on '\n' and ':' but not ' ' or '\t'.

//  ....
//  usage of the mask above.
cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new std::ctype<char>(new_table_vector.data())));
```

But is there way to include a delimiters into a resulted tokens? e.g.

> aaa&bbb*ccc%ddd&eee

where

> & * %

are delimiters defined using one of methods above.
and result strings would be:

> aaa
>
> &bbb
>
> *ccc
>
> %ddd
>
> &eee

so you see - that delimiters are included into result strings.
this is a question - how to configure (and is it possible?) input stream for that?

Thank you

Comment: To answer that, one should either prove it possible -but I would be really surprised if there were a way to configure streams for such an edge case (keep some delimiters, don't keep some, really?)- or prove it impossible but what would that entail exactly? browsing all the stream-related part of the stl and discarding one item after the other?

Comment: all delimiters is also okay, fixed the question

Comment: @amigo421 Saw you accepted my answer, thanks. I had a few more minutes so I edited it to show an example of tokenizing a slurped stream with a regex. Just wanted to update you in case that was helpful to you.

Comment: thank you. actually initial task with some abstract stream, but if there is no ability to implement this on stream level, I'll move this logic to another place with regex token iterator, something like suggested solution. thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is **no, `istream`s do not provide an inate method for extracting and retaining separators**. `istream`s provide the following extraction methods:

- [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) - discards the delimiter
- [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) - does not extract *a* delimiter at all
- [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) - discard *a* delimiter
- [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) - doesn't respect delimiters
- [`readsome`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/readsome) - doesn't respect delimiters

---

However, let's assume that you slurpped your `istream` into `string foo`, then you could use a regex like this to tokenize:

```
((?:^|[&*%])[^&*%]*)
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/nJITkf/1)

This could be used with a [`regex_token_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) like this:

```
const regex re{ "((?:^|[&*%])[^&*%]*)" };
const vector<string> bar{ sregex_token_iterator(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), re, 1), sregex_token_iterator() };
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/DMX0sJ)